# MongoDB: How to make a reference to a variable path?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, mongoose-schema, non-relational-database

I have a schema called PageSection. PageSection embeds an array of the Schema ContentItem. A content item should reference to a documents of other collections, which can be variable - like Text, Picture, Link, Checkbox, ...

```js
var PageSection = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  order: Number,
  contentItems: [{
    order: Number,
    element: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      path: "Path_to_various_models"
    }
  }]
});
```

Is this possible? Or is there an better way to that kind of variable references?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Thanks for advice for using discriminators Swagata. I didn't knew that inheritance mechanism. But anyway, I found that solution a bit complex.

I now use a solution, where ContentItem contains a field for each type of content item. Maybe its more a workaround, than a solution.

```
var PageSection = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  order: Number,
  contentItems: [{
    order: Number,
    text: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      path: "Text"
    },
    picture: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      path: "Picture"
    },
    link: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      path: "Link"
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Could you kindly clarify a little bit on `reference to elements of another model`. Do you mean it can contain objectIds from any other collection?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant - i just edited the question.

Comment: I took that into consideration and answered. Im still looking. If I find a in-built way out of mongoose I'd edit my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the question as I pointed that out in the comment before. I think you're looking for populate if 'Path to various models' means 'references to other models'. According to [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), you can do something like

```
var PageSection = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  order: Number,
  contentItems: [{
    order: Number,
    element: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    path: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }
  }]
});
```

Now, I understand that this is only for one type for one reference there, path cant be only stories.

If you have elements that come from single collection with a base type and multiple derived type you can go for [Mongoose discriminator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator) method here. You can find more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468855/multiple-schema-references-in-single-schema-array-mongoose) too. In this technique, you'd need to

1. Create a base schema for all contentItem path
2. Use a discriminator to discriminate

I still don't suggest this as it would lead to bad design.

And according to [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/52299826008/the-mean-stack-mistakes-youre-probably-making) it's better to keep the references at bay with defined types.

You can still manage references with your own way in the `contentItems` array with a id and collection/ref field and I think that would be better in this case.

Hope it helps